# Why local int variables inside `main` function will be initialized automatically?

Tags: c++, variables, program-entry-point

I'm new to C++ and have that problem while learning C++.

Here is the code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void another_func() {
    int a;
    cout << a << endl;
}

int main() {
    int a;
    cout << a << endl;
    another_func();
}
```

I'm using `g++ (GCC) 10.1.0` and I found that everytime when I run the code, the `a` inside the `main` function would be initialize to `0`, while `a` in `another_func` would be a random number. As follows,

```
➤  g++ test.cpp && ./a.out
a in main: 0
a in another_func: 32612
```

As I know, local variables are storaged in the stack and they don't have auto-initialization mechanism. So the `a` in `another_func` is expected. However, can someone tell me why the `a` in `main` function was initialized to `0`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some of it may depend on the compiler flags you've used.  You should specify those in your question.

Comment: If the arithmetic type, didn't explicitly initialized, it's could be unsigned, negative or zero, and being zero, it's doesn't mean it's has a specific behavior.

Comment: `So the a in another_func is expected` Comment out the `cout` line in `main` and run it again. You'll most likely get a different value for that other `a`, possibly even `0`.

Comment: This is called *undefined behaviour* and it is a part of C++ (and C). For some programs they break the rules in the language standard, but the compiler is not required to report a diagnosis, nor do anything sensible.  In many cases the behaviour you see is an unplanned consequence of the compiler only implementing the correct behaviour for programs which do follow the rules

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uninitialised doesn't mean non-zero, it could have any value. On many OSs freshly allocated memory pages are filled with `0` so in non-debug code uninitialised values are often `0` too.

The behaviour of your program is undefined but what is likely happening is that `a` in `main` is either the first use of the stack or you just get lucky and the initialisation code that runs before `main` leaves that area of the stack `0`.

The call to `cout` will write to the stack so when you then execute `another_func` the stack memory wont be all `0` anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The standard does not require default zero values for local variables, but some compilers might do zero initialization

Only `global` variables and `static` members must be initialized to zero unless explicitly initialized otherwise.

Comment: The "some compilers" part here really means "don't count on it".

Answer (score 2):

*tl;dr: You must not read uninitialized values.*

Both `a`s weren’t initialized to anything. That means they have an indeterminate value, which could be anything including 0. Any reasoning must stop here because **reading from an uninitialized value invokes undefined behaviour (UB).**

UB means anything can happen. Your program is invalid and you have no guarantees about anything anymore. You’re not allowed to read `a`, so reasoning about why you might read a specific value in a specific situation is not useful.

That’s the point of view of the C++ language. For writing C++ programs that’s usually the point of view you need to adopt for yourself. Of course there’s a compiler involved. More specifically, a certain compiler in a certain version with a certain configuration compiling this exact piece of code for a specific platform. Including all of that you *can* do some investigation about why you see a specific result. If you’re interested in how compilers work, that’s a useful thing to do. But it rarely helps with writing programs. Change a compiler flag or use a slightly different piece of code, and the result might be different.